# How do I implement convolution integrals symbolically (not numerically)?

Tags: symbolic, convolution, maple

I'm working to symbolically solve convolution integrals i.e., using symbolic equations and not numerical methods of integration. The general form of the convolution I'm working to solve is as follows:

[image: Convolution integral formulation]

Numerically, I have solved the convolution by sequentially sliding the kernel function across the other function and computing the bounded area. While this method works, I am using Modelica, an open-source mathematical modeling language that works on symbolic methods as opposed to numerical methods. Thus, solving the convolution numerically is time-consuming and difficult to implement when I am dealing with continuous signals.

I've been working on manipulating the convolution integral in an effort to solve this symbolically. The method I'm working on is to use Fubini's Theorem i.e., the integration of a convolution is the product of the integration of 2 integrable functions. It looks like this:

[image: Integration of a convolution integral]

So, to obtain the convolution integral, I would take the derivate of the product of integrals of these functions. In other words, differentiate the above expression to obtain the convolution integral. However, this does not appear to be working and I do not have the right answer for a test case I generated using MATLAB's in-built conv( ) function. My signal-analogy for this approach (Fubini's theorem to the integration of a convolution) is shown below:

[image: Signal analogy to Fubini's theorem application to convolution integrals]

And the result of my convolution is shown below:
The images are as follows (ordered left to right on each row):
Plot 1 - Square pulse,               Plot 2 - Integral of the square pulse,
Plot 3 - Triangular pulse,           Plot 4 - Integral of the triangular pulse,
Plot 5 - Product of the integrals,   Plot 6 - Derivative of plot 5 i.e., convolution
[image: Results of convolution - part 1]
[image: Results of convolution - part 2]

This sample case is straight off [the Wikipedia page on convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

FYI, the software I'm using is Maplesoft's MapleSim that works on the Modelica language.

If anyone has dealt with symbolically solving convolutions, I'd appreciate it if you could take a look at my work and let me know where I might me making a mistake or provide guidance on how to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the Modelica part may be obfuscating your question. If I understand you correctly, you ask how to use the formula proposed in the Wiki page to calculate the convolution of two functions *by differentiating the product of their integrals* rather than through the usual definition. You tried that, but the results do not match with the convolution calculated from the definition (which, by the way, is not currently shown in your post). Is this a good summary? If so, then you may want to remove the Modelica portion, and include the expected result.

Comment: "FYI, the software I'm using is Maplesoft's MapleSim that works on the Modelica language." Well, this site is for  *Mathematica* / Wolfram language only, so I'm afraid the question is off-topic. If the question is more about math, you may consider https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarcoB You've summarized it perfectly! I went through your solution and it makes sense. I'll drop the Modelica portion of my questions and provide the results. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 5):

On second thought, I don't think your approach to calculating the convolution is mathematically sound. The [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Integration), and [the MathWorld page it references](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html#:%7E:text=The%20area%20under%20a%20convolution%20is%20the%20product%20of%20areas%20under%20the%20factors%2C), both state that "the integral of a convolution of two integrable functions **on the whole space** is obtained as the product of their integrals on the same space". Notice the emphasis on the implied limits of integration here, i.e. the whole region.

That formula is a relationship between two numbers: the integral of the convolution of two functions over their whole function domain (the first number), and the product of the integrals of the two functions over the same domain (a second number). The fact that those two definite integrals are the same does not guarantee that the indefinite integrals (i.e. the antiderivatives) must be the same as well, which is what you would need for your method to work. Indeed, they are *not* the same, as I verify below by calculating them explicitly. They only attain the same value for large enough values of $t%; of course, lots of functions can do that without actually being identical.

Your inference that the convolution itself is then equal to the derivative of that product of integrals *in any region of that space* is unwarranted and, in fact, your calculation attempts seem to have proved it incorrect.

Reproducing your functions:

```
Clear[s1, s2]
s1[t_] := UnitBox[t/5 - 1/2];
s2[t_] := SawtoothWave[t/5] UnitBox[t/5 - 3/2]

Plot[
  {s1[x], s2[x], conv[x]}, {x, -1, 20},
  Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
]
```

[image: the two functions and their convolution]

We will first test my interpretation of the Wiki relationship, i.e. that the product of their integrals over the reals (i.e. a number) is equal to the integral of their convolution over the same range:

```
Integrate[conv[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* Out: 25/2 *)

Integrate[s1[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] * Integrate[s2[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(* Out: 25/2 *)
```

So that checks out when the integrals are over the entire $[-\infty,\infty]$ (or, for that matter, over any interval including $[0,15]$ for the results above, since all the functions involved go to zero outside that interval).

Does it work over portions of the space though? The following plot comparing the two resulting functions seems to indicate to me that it does not:

```
Plot[
  Evaluate[{
     Integrate[s1[x], x] Integrate[s2[x], x],
     Integrate[conv[x], x]
   } /. x -> t
  ],
  {t, -1, 20},
  Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotLegends -> {"product of the integrals", "integral of the convolution"}
]
```

[image: plots shows that the product of the integrals and the integral of the convolution are not the same everywhere]

And analytically:

```
Simplify[Integrate[s1[x], x] Integrate[s2[x], x]]
Simplify[Integrate[conv[x], x]]
```

[image: output (two Piecewise functions) shows that the two results are different]

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoB, but I couldn't understand what you meant by "over the whole domain" as opposed to a "portion of the space". Essentially, the system goes down to 0 for all involved functions after 15 seconds (which you've pointed out). So, shouldn't this interpretation work for any space over [0 , 15]? Why is there a difference in the product of the integrals and the integral of the convolution? Is there a specific set of conditions I need to meet to apply this mathematical formulation of convolution to a given set of functions?

Comment: @AjayMenon That formula is a relationship between two *numbers*: the integral of the convolution of two functions *over their whole function domain* (i.e. the first number), and the product of the integrals of the two functions over the same domain (i.e. another number). The fact that those two definite integrals are the same *does not guarantee* that the indefinite integrals (i.e. the antiderivatives) must be the same as well, which is what you would need for your method to work.

Comment: @AjayMenon Indeed, they are not the same, as I verified by calculating them explicitly at the end of my answer. They only attain the same value for large enough values of $t$. Of course, lots of functions can do that without actually being identical.

Comment: @AjayMenon I see that you un-accept this answer. Can I ask you why?

Comment: I'm revisiting some of the math in this question, so I didn't want to still have this marked as the answer while working on it. Once I'm done, I will either get back with more questions on this thread or mark it as the answer. In the meanwhile, I would appreciate it if you could edit your answer to include the points you raised in the comments above (June 17th comments). Thanks!

Comment: @AjayMenon Done, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

```
s1[t_] := UnitBox[t - 0.5];
s2[t_] := SawtoothWave[t] UnitBox[t - 0.5]
res = Convolve[s1[s], s2[s], s, t]
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.5 t^2 & 0.<t<1. \\
 t (1.\, -0.5 t) & 1.\leq t<2. \\
 0. & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

```
p1 = Plot[s1[x], {x, -1, 1.5}, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
p2 = Plot[s2[x], {x, -1, 1.5}, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
p3 = Plot[Evaluate[res], {t, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Darker@Green}]
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Syed, in your answer you calculated the convolution of signals similar to those proposed in the OP essentially by "using the definition". Does this address the OP's question of calculating the convolution by differentiation of the product of the integrals of the two functions being convolved, as suggested by the Wiki page? Or perhaps you are suggesting, as I did in my comments to the OP, that the most sensible MMA-based approach should be to use `Convolve` to obtain what the OP wants? In the latter case, then it may be best to use arbitrary-precision constants in your code. (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB Since the question was mostly about other platforms, I wanted to present the symbolic capabilities of Mathematica to get the OP started with signals that were almost similar.

Comment: Hi @Syed, thanks for sharing your work. I was actually looking to understand how convolutions can be symbolically represented, but it appears you've just used the in-built convolve( ) function. Any ideas on how this can be written symbolically without using the in-built function? Thanks!

Comment: `res = Integrate[
  s1[\[Tau]] s2[t - \[Tau]], {\[Tau], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` and I would preferably use the built-in `Convolve` function.